# "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (164)"

Tags: r, histogram

Here's my code that returns the error, "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (164)"

```
ggplot(data = MAT_Data, aes(x = Regression$residuals)) +
geom_histogram(fill = 'steelblue', color = 'black') +
labs(title = 'Histogram of Residuals', x = 'Residuals', y = 'Frequency')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide at least a sample of your data. That said, I think there may be a problem with the use of an object external to your data `MAT_Data` ( `Regression`) to map your aesthetics. You will usually want the aesthetics to be contained or calculated from the 'data' argument (MAT_Data)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).